# dnf not working properly on non fedora machine

Tags: linux, package-management

I have installed dnf package on custom linux distribution(non fedora). dnf can able to pull and install the .rpm packages from the configured repository.
I could not able to remove the packages via dnf remove command as dnf not maintaining the database of installed packages. Also, dnf list --installed does 
not showing the packages installed via dnf install.

Note: Both dnf and rpm packages are compiled from source. Instructions used are listed below.

dnf:

/usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/usr/src/rootfs/scripts/cmake" -DPYTHON_DESIRED:FILEPATH="/usr/bin/python3.6" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=${LIB_NAME} -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..

make

make install

rpm:

./configure --build=none --host="$TOOL_TRIPLET" --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/"$LIB_NAME" --disable-static --disable-nls --with-pcre=external --with-sqlite=yes --with-dbapi=sqlite --enable-debug=yes --with-libelf --enable-python

make

make install

Comment: The `dnf` software is a dependency manager for the `rpm` package manager.  The database of installed packages would be stored via `rpm` and that is what would be read for `dnf --installed`.  If you built `dnf` from source, you would also need to make sure `rpm` is also installed and used by your `dnf`.  If your system is not a Fedora based distribution, then the already built `rpm` packages would be useless to you and you would have to make your own `rpm` packages and repositories for your custom Linux distribution.

Comment: I have created my own `rpm` packages and stored them in a repository. Also I can able to install the rpm packages using `dnf`. When I try to list the packages installed via `dnf` its not showing list of packages installed but I can able to get the list via **rpm -qa** command. And `dnf` trying to install the dependent package though it is already installed and failing with error message 
**
Error: Transaction check error:
  package XYZ-1.0-1.x86_64 is already installed **

Comment: When I try to remove the installed packages I am getting below messages  
No match for argument: XYZ  
No packages marked for removal.  
Dependencies resolved.  
Nothing to do.  
Complete!  
  
I can also remove it via **rpm -e XYZ-1.0-1.x86_64**

Comment: It sounds like your `dnf` is not using the `rpm` which you currently have installed to build the package database.  Without knowing how you installed `dnf` or `rpm`, there is not much anyone can do to help.  Please add that information to your question to hopefully get better answers.

Comment: Both rpm and dnf packages are built from source. I have updated the instruction used in my question.

Answer (score 0):

`dnf` is the package manager for fedora. Non Fedora OS will have their own package manager.

Ubuntu has `apt-get`, redhat has `rpm`. Arch linux has `pacman` and so on.

Comment: My linux distribution doesn't have package management support at all. It is a Monolithic distribution. I am trying to add package management support to make it as modular.

Comment: Then you will have to download the source code, compile packages and install them at relevant paths to use them.

Comment: For more details, check this link https://www.howtogeek.com/105413/how-to-compile-and-install-from-source-on-ubuntu/